# webdriver selenium change hyperlink text

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to change the link text on a page using selenium WebDriver. I tried

```
test.getSeleniumElement().sendKeys(By.xpath("//span[@id='"+linktext)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript to update link text

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('LinkElementId').innerHTML='New Link Text'");
```